# Display problems in backend product page magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

Do you have any idea why I'm having this problem when I open a product page in backend ?

[image]

I'm struggling to find out what's breaking the product page. I disabled all 3rd party modules. When I refresh I have the correct display for second a half and then, boom, it simply breaks.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: did you checked  with all attribute sets product pages ? same issue in default attribute set's product page also ? flush the cache once from backend......

Comment: @BabyinMagento I already flushed all caches (even manually via ftp). All attribute sets are okay.

Comment: check log errors once, also keep this as last option. download fresh magento 1.7 set up and than take backup of your site and copy the each folders one by one and check whether it will work or not.....